# Python, saving 2 string outputs as 2 files

Tags: python, save

There are 2 string outputs. Let's call them output1 and output2. Both of them should be saved in one location, each of them should have the same name but having different file extension (both being text files in fact). 
How can this be done in Python? The program should have standard save dialog, asking for name and location. Thanks.

Comment: 'Standard save dialog'? So some sort of a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever GUI toolkit you're using to show the file dialog and get a base filename in `filename`. Then just

```
with open(filename + '.ext1', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output1)
with open(filename + '.ext2', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output2)
```